# Using canvas in javascript, to make a rhombus object out of rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to the canvas tag, and the specification for my project is to use canvas to build like a rhombus with these black borders made out of rectangles (given in the picture below):

[Rhombus from project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKhpQ.png)

This is what I got so far:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('cilim');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

    for(let i=0;i<11;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(i*50,0,50,50);
        ctx.rect(0,i*50,50,50);
        ctx.rect(i*50,10*50,50,50);
        ctx.rect(10*50,i*50,50,50);
        ctx.lineWidth=1;
        ctx.strokeStyle="lightgrey";
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    for(let i=1;i<10;i++){
        for(let j=1;j<10;j++){
            if((i+j===6) || Math.abs((i-j))===4 || (i+j)===14){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(i*50,j*50,50,50);
                ctx.lineWidth=2;
                ctx.strokeStyle="black";
            }else{
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(i*50,j*50,50,50);
                ctx.lineWidth=3;
                ctx.strokeStyle="lightgrey";

            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cilim</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="cilim" width="550px" height="550px"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any other way to make these black borders, where did I go wrong, or can I use any other object in canvas to create that type of rhombus. Any feedback, suggestion is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a 2D array

There are many ways to do this. The simplest is also the most flexible.

Create a map from a string. Using a character to define inside cells.
Covert the string to a 2D array
Step over each cell, if the cell contains the inside character, check each cell left, above, right, and below. For each edge if there is no inside character at that position in the array you know it must have an edge drawn.

### Example.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), size = 50;
const map = `..........,
.....#....,
....###...,
...#####..,
..#######.,
.#########,
..#######.,
...#####..,
....###...,
.....#....
`.split(",").map(row => [...row.trim()]);
createGrid();
outlineCells(map);
function outlineCells(map) {
    var x, y;
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
        const row = map[y];
        for (x = 0; x < row.length; x++) {
            if (row[x] === "#") {
               const xx = x * size, yy = y * size;
               if (row[x - 1] !== "#") {  // left edge
                  ctx.moveTo(xx, yy + size);
                  ctx.lineTo(xx, yy);               
               }
               if (y === 0 || map[y - 1][x] !== "#") {  // top edge
                  ctx.moveTo(xx, yy);
                  ctx.lineTo(xx + size, yy);               
               }
               if (row[x + 1] !== "#") {  // right edge
                  ctx.moveTo(xx + size, yy);
                  ctx.lineTo(xx + size, yy + size);               
               }
               if (y === map.length - 1 || map[y + 1][x] !== "#") {  // top edge
                  ctx.moveTo(xx, yy + size);
                  ctx.lineTo(xx + size, yy + size);               
               }
           }
       }
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
function createGrid() {
    ctx.strokeStyle = "lightgrey";
    ctx.beginPath();
    for(let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        ctx.rect(0, i * size, 11 * size, size);
        ctx.rect(i * size, 0, size, 11 * size);
   }
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="550"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just tried something similar to your answer, for those black borders I used moveTo and and lineTo, checked the diagonals and it works.